# Javascript - Rounding a number

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

the result from this function is 5.4 ... but i need 5.40.
It is a simple question but i have no (clean) idea to resolve this.

**JS**

```
var test = round(-5.401826873479466,2);

alert(test+' $'); // = 5.4 $

function round(number, decimals) {
    return Math.round(number * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);   
}
```

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/xMXPz/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is for displaying the string, then you need [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) :

```
function round(number, decimals) {
   return number.toFixed(decimals)
}
```

This returns a string. There is no difference, in JS encoding of numbers, between `5.4` and `5.40`. [Read more in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var test = round(-5.401826873479466,2);
test=test.toFixed(2);
alert(test+' $');

function round(number, decimals)                                {

return Math.round(number * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
```

}

Comment: Then again, the OP could always just use [*Number.prototype.toPrecision*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.7).